# Parsing Multiple Nested XML file to Data table using C#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am trying to read the Nested XML file to a single dataset using C# and have tried using the Linq and XDocument and didn't find any luck, So Can someone help me in parsing the XML file and Thanks in advance.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filenamepath);
       XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Columns.Add("Shipment ID", typeof(string));
       dt.Columns.Add("Delivery Number", typeof(string));

       XElement referenceNumber = doc.Descendants(ns + "ReferenceNumber").FirstOrDefault();
       string shipmentID = (string)referenceNumber.Element(ns + "Shipment ID");
       string deliveryNumber = (string)referenceNumber.Element(ns + "Delivery Number");
```

Comment: You have a very complicated xml file with NO schema.  It requires a custom parser!!!  Using standard DataSet ReadXML file only works with limited number of descendants. The dataset method uses the root tag as the dataset name.  The next level of tags are the datatable names.The 3rd level tags are the column names.  The 4th level tags are the row data.Once you have more than or level of tags the dataset method fragments the dataset into pieces that cannot be recombined into a usable format.I can help if you need sections of the xml parsed, but it would take a full day form me to do entire file.

Comment: What is the expected output here? I only see two unique shipment id / delivery numbers, BH30005632 / 0860017651 and BH30005633 / 0860017652. So do you want a data table with two rows in with those two pairings?

Comment: I agree this a very complex XML file . Let say the parent nodes Shipments & Plan  i need 2 data tables which will loop through the child nodes reference Numbers ..etc

Answer (score 0):

I parsed some of the xml using xml linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("BOL ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("BOL Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("BOL Created By", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("BOL Created Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("BOL Updated By", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("BOL Updated Date", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Columns.Add("Reference Number Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Reference Number Primary", typeof(Boolean));
            dt.Columns.Add("Reference Number ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Reference Number", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            List<XElement> masterBillOfLadings = root.Elements("MasterBillOfLading").ToList();

            foreach (XElement masterBillOfLading in masterBillOfLadings)
            {
                string bolId = (string)masterBillOfLading.Attribute("internalId");
                string bolType = (string)masterBillOfLading.Attribute("type");
                string bolCreatedBy = (string)masterBillOfLading.Attribute("createBy");
                DateTime bolCreatedDate = (DateTime)masterBillOfLading.Attribute("createDate");
                string bolUpdatedBy = (string)masterBillOfLading.Attribute("updateBy");
                DateTime bolUpdatedDate = (DateTime)masterBillOfLading.Attribute("updateDate");

                XElement referenceNumbers = masterBillOfLading.Element("ReferenceNumbers");
                foreach (XElement referenceNumber in referenceNumbers.Elements("ReferenceNumber"))
                {
                    string referenceNumberType = (string)referenceNumber.Attribute("type");
                    Boolean referenceNumberPrimary = (Boolean)referenceNumber.Attribute("isPrimary");
                    string referenceNumberID = (string)referenceNumber.Attribute("internalId");
                    string referenceNumberStr = (string)referenceNumber;

                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        bolId,
                        bolType,
                        bolCreatedBy,
                        bolCreatedDate,
                        bolUpdatedBy,
                        bolUpdatedDate,
                        referenceNumberType,
                        referenceNumberPrimary,
                        referenceNumberID,
                        referenceNumberStr
                    });

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```